# How to grep with regex lookahead

Tags: grep

I can't see what I'm missing in my grep command, can you?

http://regexr.com/5shri

`echo "2021-05-09 15:38:56.888 T:1899877296  NOTICE: VideoPlayer::OpenFile:plugin://plugin.video.arteplussept/play/SHOW/069083-002-A" | grep -oE "\w+(?=\/play)/g" -`

Expect: *arteplussept*

Comment: Yes, `grep -oP '\w+(?=/play)'`

Comment: See also: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/109046)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

- Use the PCRE regex engine, with `-P` option, not `-E` (which stands for POSIX ERE)
- Remove `/g`, `grep -o` extracts *all* matches and there is no need to "embed" this modifier into the pattern
- There is no need to escape `/`

So, you can just use

```sh
grep -oP '\w+(?=/play)'
```